# Connect Graphic Card SPDIF input cable to Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, graphics-card, spdif

How do I connect  the graphic card SPDIF-in cable (2 pin blue and black) to motheboard connector SPDIF-out (3 pin red,white,black).

Comment: I have connected the cable. Now I have only a problem that audio drop out every 2-3 seconds. Maybe is a HDMI audio problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/600/2) explains which wire should connect to each pin (red wire to the SPDO pin, black wire to the GND pin) and includes photos. Check the labels on the motherboard carefully.